# Divide long string in multiple section without break sentence

Tags: php, html

I have long string in php database and I want to dived in 5 section without breaking sentence. If my long text dived in 4 section then remaining section not to be display.

I use substr(), but there is not complete sentence.
Here is sample my php code:

```
$first = substr($story, 0, 1000);
$second = substr($story, 1001, 2000);
$third = substr($story, 2001, 3000);
$fourth = substr($story, 3001, 3800);
```

Here i attach output sample to display long text in 2 section.
[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqRAl.png)

Please help me to dived long string in multiple section without section break.

Comment: You can use css for that. try `text-align:justify` without php

Answer (score 0):

How about something using the wordwrap function?  With conjunction with explode, you can split these chunks into an array, breaking on a word at or under you character limit:

```
$unique_marker = "**!!**";      // A temporary and unique delimter for the explode
$trim_under = 1000;             // Split chunk under this character limit
$lines = explode($unique_marker, wordwrap($story, $trim_under, $unique_marker, true));
print_r($lines);                // Show us the contents of the array
```

I havent tested it, but the above code should get you pointed in the right direction...